# trying to get two columns to stand side by side

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3 class="heading-h3 p1-h3">Modern Standard</h3>
      <p class="p1">
         Sometimes copy and pasting some jQuery plugins doesn't cut it. I can help create truly bespoke solutions based on requirements
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      <i class="ion-social-html5"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      <i class="ion-social-html5"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3 class="heading-h3 p2-h3">Responsive Design experience</h3>
      <p class="p2">
         By using bootstrap I ensure most projects work cross device out of the box
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3 class="heading-h3 p3-h3">Available full time</h3>
      <p class="p3">
         This is my main job, so i'm available 9-5 on phone/email/Skype.
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      <i class="ion-social-html5"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      <i class="ion-social-html5"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3 class="heading-h3 p4-h3">Reliable and trusted by clients</h3>
      <p class="p4">
         Whilst some freelancers go AWOL when the going gets tough, i've worked with few clients for time now
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3 class="heading-h3 p5-h3">Built with Scalability</h3>
      <p class="p5">
         I can help advise the best methodology to ensure your project grows with you.
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      <i class="ion-social-html5"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      <i class="ion-social-html5"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3 class="heading-h3 p6-h3">5-star Support</h3>
      <p class="p6">
         Sometimes building the site is half the work, i'm always around to provide ongoing support.
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have been trying to get the two columns `col-sm-4` and `col-sm-2` to stand side by side. A content and an icon stand beside it on small device using media queries and am using Bootstrap 4, I just just can't get it to be responsive.

Comment: Hey stanley, welcome to SO! You did well turning your code into a Stack Snippet. However, it looks like you forgot to add the CSS? Also, you could remove quite a bit of whitespace there to make it more legible. Also, try the "Tidy" button within the Snippet editor.

Comment: sorry about that, is kinda my first time, will do better next time

Comment: No need to be sorry; I'm pointing it out so you can do better *this* time - note the "edit" link at the bottom of your question? You can use that to improve it as suggested. :)

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. Using

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css

Testing pen here: http://amat.me/stackoverflow-44730863

Comment: Thanks, so sorry my question wasn't clear enough, I was so fustrated with this issues. What I wanted to do, is to make some changes in media queries. Like adding bootstrap 4 class to a column.for example..

Comment: . col-sm-9 { order: flex-start; }...  Just wanted to know if it's possible to add flexbox order to an element right inside media queries. I might just change my layout

Answer (score 0):

Having the columns next to each other is working. But you should start a new row every now and then.

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h3 class="heading-h3 p1-h3">Modern Standard</h3>
    <p class="p1">
      Sometimes copy and pasting some jQuery plugins doesn't cut it. I can help create truly bespoke solutions based on requirements
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <i class="ion-social-html5"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <i class="ion-social-html5"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h3 class="heading-h3 p2-h3">Responsive Design experience</h3>
    <p class="p2">
      By using bootstrap I ensure most projects work cross device out of the box
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h3 class="heading-h3 p3-h3">Available full time</h3>
    <p class="p3">
      This is my main job, so i'm available 9-5 on phone/email/Skype.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <i class="ion-social-html5"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <i class="ion-social-html5"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h3 class="heading-h3 p4-h3">Reliable and trusted by clients</h3>
    <p class="p4">
      Whilst some freelancers go AWOL when the going gets tough, i've worked with few clients for time now
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h3 class="heading-h3 p5-h3">Built with Scalability</h3>
    <p class="p5">
      I can help advise the best methodology to ensure your project grows with you.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <i class="ion-social-html5"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <i class="ion-social-html5"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h3 class="heading-h3 p6-h3">5-star Support</h3>
    <p class="p6">
      Sometimes building the site is half the work, i'm always around to provide ongoing support.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks will try that